# Python 3.x Tortoise-orm Delete all values inside the database SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, tortoise-orm

So I've recently  starting learning about tortoise-orm. But I have a question: How would I get all the data inside the SQLite database and delete all of them?

Ex Model:

```py
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import fields

class Counter(Model):
    count = fields.IntField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can :

- get all the data by querying `Counter.all()`. Awaiting this will give you a python list of `Counter` objects.
- delete the entire database by doing, `await Tortoise._drop_database()`

**BEWARE OF DROPPING THE DATABSE, YOU WILL LOSE ALL YOU DATA**

> Tries to drop all databases provided in config passed to .init() method. Normally should be used only for testing purposes.